# Calling unittest.main() in PyCharm - AtrributeError: module '__main__' has no atrribute

Tags: python, pycharm

I think this is more a PyCharm question than unittest question, but I'm studying testing from a book and this example is failing me as written.  I'm running PyCharm 2016.3.2 and Python 3.6

```
import unittest
from name_function import get_formatted_name

class NamesTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for 'name_function.py'."""

    def test_first_last_name(self):
        """Do names like 'Janis Joplin' work?"""
        formatted_name = get_formatted_name('janis', 'joplin')
        self.assertEqual(formatted_name, 'Janis Joplin')

# In book, it's just the unittest.main() , which does not work...
# So in PyCharm __name__ doesn't equal __main__ ... not sure why
# if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here is name_function.py:

```
def get_formatted_name(first, last):
    """Generate a neatly formatted full name."""
    full_name = first + " " + last
    return full_name.title()
```

If I run it as written, I get the following error:

```
EE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_name_function (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'test_name_function'

======================================================================
ERROR: true (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'true'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s
```

If I let the "if" statement run (or just delete the call to unittest.main()) then it works properly, with no main() call at all.

This is all in a `test_name_function.py`.  So it seems like when running this one file (and importing `name_function.py`) that PyCharm does not consider this one file to be `__main__` ?  Is PyCharm doing something else behind the scenes?

I'm new to Python and PyCharm and trying to get my head around the structure and environment.  Thanks very much guys.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Filip

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to figure it out.

```
 suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(NamesTestCase)
 unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```